# Tasm pointer to data

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need to load characters from input string one by one, however I am unable to, as my pointer points to bad location it seems. Essentially my biggest problem is that I don't know how to make something like `mov dl, buffer+bl`. Here is the code:

```
.model small
.stack 200h

.data
buffer  db 16 dup(?)
p db ?  ;pointer

.code
pr1:

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

;read input
mov dx, offset buffer
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h 

;cycle set up
mov bl, 02h
mov cl, buffer+01h  

;new line
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 10
int 21h

;cycle for each symbol
ciklas:

    mov p, offset buffer
    add p, bl
    mov dl, [p]

    int 21h

    inc bl

loop ciklas 

mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 00h
int 21h

end pr1
```

My program is supposed to reprint the input, however it prints various smiles instead

Comment: `movzx bx, bl; mov dl, [buffer+bx]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer of [`Int 21/AH=0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) has three parts: size, length, string. The size is the maximal size of the string and **must** be initialized.

Change

```
buffer  db 16 dup(?)
```

to

```
buffer  db 16, 0, 16 dup(?)
```

Consider, that the string starts at `buffer + 2`.

An offset has a size of 16 byte. If you want to store an offset into `p`, `p` must have the same size.

Change

```
p db ?  ;pointer
```

to

```
p dw ?  ;pointer
```

The loop loops by `CX`. Initialize it as late as possible. You don't know, if a call to a function  (`int 21h`) destroys it. If you can only load `CL`, you can nullify `CH` (the other part of `CX`) with `xor ch, ch`. You don't need the buggy fuss with `p`, there is a processor instruction that does it (keyword: base plus index). My suggestion:

```
;cycle for each symbol
xor ch, ch
mov cl, buffer+01h
xor bx, bx                  ; BX = 0
ciklas:
    mov dl, [buffer + 2 + bx]
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    inc bx
loop ciklas
```